# min and max value of string in c

Tags: c

The function receives a single string as well as the address that will store the minimum and maximum values. For example when the string 1+2+3 is passed, the function should store 1 at the address contained in min and 3 and the address contained the max.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

void maxValue(char *s, int *min, int *max);
int main(void)
{
    int i,col, min, max;
    char *text[] = {"1+2+3"};
    col = sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]);
    for(i=0; i<col; i++)
    {
        maxValue(text[i], &min, &max);
        printf("min = %d, max = %d", min, max);
    }
}

void maxValue(char *s, int *min, int *max)
{
    int i;
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    char* del = "+";
    char* token;
    strcpy(temp, s);
    token = strtok(temp, del);

    int stringInts = atoi(token);
    for(i=0; i<stringInts; i++)
    {
        if(*min < stringInts)
            *min = stringInts;
        if (*max > stringInts) {
            *max = stringInts;
        }
    } 
}
```

This function is not working correct. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you modifying `max`?

Comment: are you new to `C` or you have written `pseudocode`??

Comment: What is `ints` in function `maxValue` ? are you posted compiled code?

Comment: The posted code is not compilable code. Can you copy and paste the code that you are actually working with?

Comment: I have reedited the code it was a typo in my writing.

Comment: This code has several childish errors.

Comment: what have you edited??see your function prototype..it do not contains the `data type`..you are missing `;`

Comment: Okay I just pasted in the code i'm working on?

Comment: @rock321987 now the code should be compiling since I just pasted the code I'm working on

Comment: Can I give you similar solution. Because you have complexed the way to do simplest thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of places where you needed to verify your syntax and use of strtok. As you go forward with C, each line, each character is important. If you don't know why it is there, well... look it up...

That being so, you had roughed-out an approach to extracting the min and max from the string by use of your `maxValue` function. You were challenged in dotting the i's and crossing the t's to get it to work. While there are many ways to do it, sticking with your approach, this is probably a working implementation of what you were attempting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void maxValue(char *s, int *min, int *max);

int main(void)
{
    int min = 0, max = 0;
    char text[] = "1+2+3";

    maxValue (text, &min, &max);
    printf("\nmin = %d, max = %d\n\n", min, max);

    return 0;
}

void maxValue(char *s, int *min, int *max)
{
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    char* del = "+";
    int token[3];
    strcpy(temp, s);

    token[0] = atoi (strtok(temp, del));
    token[1] = atoi (strtok(NULL, del));
    token[2] = atoi (strtok(NULL, del));

    int i = 0;
    *min = token[0];
    *max = token[0];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        *max = (*max < token[i]) ? token[i] : *max;
        *min = (*min > token[i]) ? token[i] : *min;
    } 
}
```

output:

```
min = 1, max = 3
```

Every time you declare a variable, initialize it, give it a value unless you have a good reason for delaying it. Think about whether you need an array or a pointer to an array. Also, if you are dealing with 3 values, do you really need a loop? all are consideration you should evaluate and decide upon. As said, this is just a way to do what you were attempting. It is far from the best way, but the intent was to show you what you were doing -- would work, with just a bit of polish (and syntax).

To generalize `maxValue` so that it can handle any number of values in `s`, you would simply have to rework the logic. Recall, the above example was done to implement what your original code suggested. You can eliminate much of the logic and replace it with a simple `while` loop that checks the return of `strtok` and if it is not `NULL` test for min/max. For example:

```
void maxValue(char *s, int *min, int *max)
{
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    char* del = "+";
    int token;
    char* ptr = NULL;
    strcpy(temp, s);

    token = atoi (strtok(temp, del));
    *min = token;
    *max = token;

    while ((ptr = strtok(NULL, del)) != NULL) 
    {
        token = atoi (ptr);
        *max = (*max < token) ? token : *max;
        *min = (*min > token) ? token : *min;
    } 
}
```

input:

```
char text[] = "1+2+3+4+5+6";
```

output:

```
min = 1, max = 6
```

Comment: What about if we had more that 3 values in this case `char* text = {"1+2+3+4", "3+4+5+6+7, "9+6+4+2"};

Comment: In that case you would change `maxValue` so that you count the number of `+` in `s`, call it `ndelms`, then you know that the number of values you have is `ndelm+1`. Instead of using a fixed number of tokens, change `tokens[3]` to a simple `int *tokens`. Knowing then number of terms you can then set `tokens = malloc (sizeof(int) * (ndelms+1)`. Then simply put your `strtok(NULL,del)` calls in a `while` or `for` loop and either assign all tokens or simply test max/min after each `atoi(strtok(NULL,del)` call. That would pretty much do it. If you do max/min test after strtok, only 1 tokens is used

Comment: Could visually eraborate what you mean. I don't seem to understand since I just started working with pointers

Comment: Yes, done, check the answer. In the future, we will expect you to show us what you have done and where you are having trouble. Everybody needs a little help now and then.